# Difference between Subdomain, hostname, host and www in a DNS system?

Tags: dns

I am studying DNS from various sources on the internet and cannot comprehend above mentioned terms. I cannot get a real life example of above terms anywhere. What I understand is:

Domain: com, edu, us, pk are examples.

Subdomain: anything that comes before the above mentioned TLD (top level domains)

Hostname: Specific web server name.

WWW: similar to hostname.

Not to mention FQDN!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically, "domain" and "subdomain" are the same entities, except that the "sub" prefix indicates a relationship between two domains. So you can basically talk of a "subdomain" only in relationship to another domain. For example `google.com` and `corp.google.com` both are domains, but `corp.google.com` is a subdomain of `google.com`. `google.com` itself is also a subdomain, a subdomain of top level domain (TLD) `com`.

TLDs are the only domains that you can't talk of as "subdomains", because they don't have any higher-level domain above them.

It's similar to how a file system on a computer is organized: `/usr` and `/usr/bin` are both folders, but `/usr/bin` is a subfolder of `/usr`. `/usr` is a subfolder of the root folder (`/`). The root folder is the only folder that isn't a subfolder of anything.

Technically, any domain should have one or more **NS records** in the DNS, specifying the name server(s) serving that domain. It is possible to define a domain without it's own NS record, but this is considered trickery. One shouldn't set up DNS like that.

Hostname - as said in the other answer - is just an individual name assigned to a computer. If you combine hostname with domain, you get a Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN), that identifies a particular computer in the DNS. Any FQDN should translate to an **A record** in the DNS, specifying the IP address assigned to that FQDN (or AAAA record in case of IPv6 addresses).

One computer can have multiple hostnames and/or multiple FQDNs (even in different domains) which may be assigned either to the same IP address or to different IP addresses - this is fully flexible.

For example, `ns1.google.com` is a FQDN of one of the Google's name servers. `ns1` is a hostname here (we sometimes call it a **hostname part of the FQDN**), and `google.com` is a domain (similarly, a **domain part of the FQDN**).

Note that the domain name itself may also be considered a FQDN, especially when the domain itself is also assigned an A record, as it is common nowadays (see below).

`www` is just a specific hostname that is customarily used to identify the main web server for the given domain. So `www.google.com` is FQDN of Google's main web server. It is common nowadays to configure DNS so that the domain itself also has A record that refers to the same IP address that the `www` hostname, so typing for example `https://google.com` and `https://www.google.com` brings you to the same website.

Of course hostnames/FQDNs are not used only for webservers; any computer in the network can have a hostname/FQDN. For example, Gmail's incoming and outgoing mail servers have FQDNS `imap.gmail.com` and `smtp.gmail.com`. You don't type these FQDNs into the web browser, because there's no web service on these machines; but you use them eg. when configuring your mail client to use Gmail.

Comment: @Keltari Please explain what exactly is not correct and maybe write your own answer that is correct.

Comment: This is a very useful answer.  However one thing stands out to me as curious: if the root of a volume (`/`) is also considered a folder, why is the root of the domain system (`.`) not also considered a domain?

Answer (score 2):

Host is a device within network.

Host can have hostname if it is exposed to network. (It can have a hostname on its own, but it basically means it has at least link local network).

Any hostname is a subdomain except if it is a TLD.

www can be a hostname if it is assigned to a specific host withing a network or can be a subdomain where lower level hosts are located, like server1.www.example.net. It's up to network administrator to decide final configuration for better readability and maintainability.

2nd level subdomain (simply domain after TLD) can be assigned to host as a hostname. Then some device can be accessible by just short address e.g. example.org.

TLD teoretically can be assigned to a device as a hostname, but it is not done due to network management standards and agreements especially for public TLDs. Howevr I have encountered private networks with devices assigned private TLDs within that network.

Answer (score 1):

### Domain

A domain is what you type into the address bar. ex `google.com`

### Subdomain

A subdomain is what comes before the domain. ex `support.` the full thing would be `support.google.com`

### Hostname

A hostname is the name of a computer on a network. This doesn't have link to domains or subdomains. for example a computer could have a hostname of `hostname` and linked to a domain called `domain.com`. On windows this is generaly `DESKTOP-XXXXXX`

### WWW

I am asuming that you mean the www in the web address like `www.google.com`

This is just a subdomain. If you want to learn about why people use it you can watch [this video by TheoJoe](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=video&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjVhs-n-pnwAhUfDjQIHQMbBqMQtwIwAHoECAIQAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D8Fq-hsGYS-8&usg=AOvVaw2tAFVZa8eZHBEaAfNF3COq)

Comment: The video is too fast for a beginner like me to understand. I would be grateful if a more explanatory book or a resource online is available. Thanks

Comment: @AJHUNTER the video was just the history. the gist is that the `www` is just used to identify something as a web address. There the `www` is just a subdomain.

Answer (score -1):

The only correct answer here is by Raj.

A hostname and a subdomain are NOT interchangeable. If you have a domain, such as mydomain.net, ANYTHING that comes before that, as in WWW.mydomain.net, is a hostname.

The relevant info from Raj:

> Technically, any domain should have one or more NS records in the DNS, specifying the name server(s) serving that domain. It is possible to define a domain without it's own NS record, but this is considered trickery. One shouldn't set up DNS like that.

If WWW in the example is actually a subdomain, then it has to have it's own NS records. then any hosts in THAT subdomain would be like SRV1.WWW.mydomain.net.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Actually, Raj's answer is incorrect.  Fortunately, your answer (which should be a comment, not an answer) brought this to the top.  I will write the correct answer shortly.

Comment: The last part of the post is incorrect in several ways at once. DNS since day one has supported deeper hierarchies without requiring a NS delegation.